# Environmental variance model: How to obtain slope, RMSE and regression p-values for each level of fixed effects in a linear mixed model made with lmer

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, covariance-matrix

**Dear everyone,**

I am trying to obtain linear regression details for my linear mixed model (LMM) created with the lme4 package in R.

I have a LMM with Yield as response variable and four levels of Treatments (fixed effect) and Year is considered a random effect.

```
model2 <- lmer(Yield ~ Treatment + (1 | mean_yearly_yield), data = join_test)
```

With the summary(model2)

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: Yield ~ Treatment + (1 | mean_yearly_yield)
   Data: join_test

REML criterion at convergence: 520.3

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.48296 -0.63412  0.04378  0.61727  2.23359 

Random effects:
 Groups            Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 mean_yearly_yield (Intercept) 2.133    1.461   
 Residual                      1.283    1.132   
Number of obs: 156, groups:  mean_yearly_yield, 13

Fixed effects:
                         Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                2.6177     0.4438  15.6535   5.898 2.46e-05 ***
TreatmentFertilizer        1.5484     0.2565 140.0000   6.038 1.33e-08 ***
TreatmentGliricidia        1.0993     0.2565 140.0000   4.287 3.36e-05 ***
TreatmentGliricidia+50%F   1.9601     0.2565 140.0000   7.643 3.05e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) TrtmnF TrtmnG
TrtmntFrtlz -0.289              
TrtmntGlrcd -0.289  0.500       
TrtmnG+50%F -0.289  0.500  0.500
```

and anova output

```
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
          Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
Treatment 83.463  27.821     3   140  21.692 1.347e-11 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

With this plot [image: Plot]

**My question is:** How can I derive the regression values for each treatment such as Intercept with std errors, Slope with std errors, R2, RMSE and p-values.

Like this example from a paper "Can Integration of Legume Trees Increase Yield Stability in Rainfed Maize Cropping Systems in Southern Africa?" by Sileshi et al. (2012) – here they used PROC MIXED from SAS. **Is the same possible with R?**

[image]

Comment: Note that this question is also asked here: [www.researchgate.net/post/Environmental_variance_model_How_to_obtain_slope_RMSE_and_regression_p-values_for_each_level_of_fixed_effects_in_a_linear_mixed_model](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Environmental_variance_model_How_to_obtain_slope_RMSE_and_regression_p-values_for_each_level_of_fixed_effects_in_a_linear_mixed_model)

Comment: See the example of Figure 1 in this article
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232925142_Fertilizer_Rate_Effects_on_Forage_Yield_Stability_and_Nutrient_Uptake_of_Midland_Bermudagrass 
where they use the same approach as in the original paper from where my data comes from. What I struggle with is obtaining the intercept and slope of the individual treatments, basically the regression equation and the accommodating std.error and RMSE.

Comment: I have proceeded by using the ggpmisc package and adding regression formulas for each of the treatments e.g. see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61357383/label-ggplot-with-group-names-and-their-equation-possibly-with-ggpmisc However, I still need the RMSEs any suggestions?